# How to access R (raster object ) in java

Tags: java, r, object, raster

I have seen Rserve is used to connect to R in java. From that I want to access raster object of R in java.
Can any one suggest examples like accessing R object from java

Answer (score 1):

For using Rserve:

Firstly, you need to use linux root permission tp startup R and install Rserve package.

```
~ sudo R
> install.packages("Rserve")
installing via 'install.libs.R' to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rserve
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (Rserve)
```

Secondly, startup Rserve.

```
~ R CMD Rserve

R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"
Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Rserv started in daemon mode.
```

Then check the process `Rserve` and check the interface of network

```
~ ps -aux|grep Rserve
panda     7142  0.0  1.2 116296 25240 ?        Ss   09:13   0:00 /usr/lib/R/bin/Rserve

~ netstat -nltp|grep Rserve
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6311          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7142/Rserve
```

**For Rserve works on Windows**, you just need to run these commands in the RGui.

```
> install.packages('Rserve')
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/Rserve_1.7-3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 711910 bytes (695 KB)
downloaded 695 KB

package ‘Rserve’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\panda\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Rtmpw7mlQY\downloaded_packages
> library(Rserve)
> Rserve()
Starting Rserve...
 "D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\library\Rserve\libs\x64\Rserve.exe"  
>
```

Now, the Rserve is started and its port is 6311. You can continue to connect it in Java. If you want to use Rserve as a Remote Server, you need to run the command `R CMD Rserve --RS-enable-remote`. The remote server port is 7173 that check the port thru command `netstat -nltp|grep Rserve` again.

This is a simple Java code for Rserve. You need to download the dependent jar libs `REngine.jar` and `RserveEngine.jar` at http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/files/. You can create a Java Project to develop the code for Rserve.

```
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXP;
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException;

public class Demo1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RserveException, REXPMismatchException {
        Demo1 demo = new Demo1();
        demo.callRserve();
    }

    public void callRserve() throws RserveException, REXPMismatchException {
        RConnection c = new RConnection("192.168.1.201");
        REXP x = c.eval("R.version.string");
        System.out.println(x.asString());//打印变量x

        double[] arr = c.eval("rnorm(10)").asDoubles();
        for (double a : arr) {//循环打印变量arr
            System.out.print(a + ",");
        }
    }
}
```

The result of code above is:

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
1.7695224124757984,-0.29753038160770323,0.26596993631142246,1.4027325257239547,-0.30663565983302676,-0.17594309812158912,0.10071253841443684,0.9365455161259986,0.11272119436439701,0.5766373030674361,
```

I think you can follow the APIs of Rserve in Eclipse to guess their usage easily.

Best Regards.

Comment: can you tell for windows

Comment: @user28536 I works on Linux. But I think it can running on Windows. You can try to do these steps in Windows CMD.

Comment: could you help me to tell the way of  reading  Landsat data's .tif file in from java using R command

Comment: what in is the command for installing Rserve in windows from command prompt

Comment: I am afrid that I couldn't gone though the commands from windows

Comment: @user28536 I tried to install and run Rserve on Windows successfully. Please see my updated post. But Rserve works on Windows it is not recommended, and that is only one connection at a time is allowed and all subsequent connections share the same namespace. Could you mark it answer? Thanks.

Comment: I can able to connect R from java using package org.rosuda.REngine. Now I want to pass R code raster(".tif") file as input to R function reflcon(). Then how can I pass tif file as input to R function using java